# How to add a new static parameter without affecting the olders one?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to read from the user the name of the fabricant and the type of the key. I have defined a class "article" with a String fabricant and a List of types of keys. If I have to add a new type it's okay but if I have to add a new fabricant, the new name of the fabricant changes the one who was before. This is the code( the class Allarticle it's a Set of Articles):

```
Cle.mType = textntype.getText();
Set <String> nType = new HashSet<>();
boolean found = false;
String antes =  Article.mFabricant;

Allarticle allarticle = new Allarticle();
allarticle.importFrom("article.txt");
for(String fabric : allarticle.getFabricants()){

    if(fabric.equals(antes)){
        found = true;
        allarticle.getTypeForFabricant(antes).add(textntype.getText());
        allarticle.exportTo("article.txt");   
    }
}
if(found == false){

    nType.add(textntype.getText());
    allarticle.addArticle(new Article(antes,nType));
    allarticle.exportTo("article.txt");
}
```

With the debug I have founded the problem inside the second if in the add function. I think it has something related to the fact that the variable mFabricant is static but I cant change it because I need it in others Jframe.
This is the function addArticle and the class Article:

```
public void addArticle(Article article){
   mArticles.add(article);
}

public class Article {

protected static String mFabricant;
protected Set<String> mType;}
```

This is the code for the firs Jframe where I get the value from and itembox:

```
    Article.mFabricant = (String) articlesbox.getSelectedItem();
    Cle.mFabricant = (String) articlesbox.getSelectedItem();
    TypeFE obj = new TypeFE();
    obj.setVisible(true);
    dispose();
```

And here is the code for select the type of key based on the fabricant:

```
 public TypeFE() {
    initComponents();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Type");
    Allarticle allarticle = new Allarticle();
    allarticle.importFrom("article.txt");
    Set <String> marticles;
    marticles = allarticle.getTypeForFabricant(Article.mFabricant);
    for(String article : marticles){
        typebox.addItem(article);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable mFabricant, being static in nature, is shared across all instances of Article which means that setting its value through any Article instance will over-write it for all instances.

Please share the code where you are using it in the JFrame.

I would suggest that you change the 'mFabricant' to instance field and pass the reference of either mFabricant or Article instance to JFrame.

Change TypeFE class constructor to take fabricant as parameter:

```
public TypeFE(final String fabricant) {
   ....

  marticle = allarticles.getTypeForFabricant(fabricant);
   .....
}
```

Pass selected fabricant in your TyprFE initialization:

```
final String fabricant =  (String) articlesbox.getSelectedItem();
TypeFE obj = new TypeFE(fabricant);
obj.setVisible(true);
dispose();
```

You can search this fabricant value in your list of articles and add a type if article exist or add a new article.

Comment: Thank you! I have edit le comment with more information, if I use the getFabricant method the value will be the same in all the Jframe?.The problem I found is that article its no defined in the new frame so I'll have to defined in every Jframe, in that case, the value would be different, no? I dont know very well how memory storage works in Java. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have changed the answer to suggest changes in your code. If anything is unclear then please sharr the releveant claases with me through email and i would be happy to assist you with the changes. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt realize that I could change the class constructor of a Jframe! That works perfect now. Thank you again